# Unique file name generation out of a couple of variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, naming

I am running some calculations in python that are time consuming and I would like to serialize the intermediate results.

My problem is the following: each calculation is configured by multiple parameters: a couple of numbers and strings. Of course, I can concatenate everything, but it will be also extremely long string and I am afraid that it will exceed allowed length of a file name.

Any ideas how to cope with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to use md5 (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html)

```
import md5
tmp=md5.new()
tmp.update(<parameter1>)
...
filename=tmp.hexdigest()
```

This should generate filenames which are unique enough. You can add the current timestamp as a parameter to raise uniqueness.